# Creating a table() of counts using a frequency column

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got data created from the `HairEyeColor` data

```r
HEC = as.data.frame(HairEyeColor)
```

which is a quick way of generating a data frame with a Frequency column, which is my situation.

I need to create contingency tables similar to this:

```
          colhair
coleye black blond brunette red
blue      20    94       84  17
brown     68     7      119  26
green      5    16       29  14
hazel     15    10       54  14
```

Note: I'm not asking how to do it with the existing HairEyeColor data table, but with a data frame that has a frequency column.

I have tried several varieties of `table()`, `xtabs()`, and aggregate() and the best I can do is get is counts of rows. I can't seem to get the frequency column to be productively used.

[plyr](/questions/tagged/plyr) solutions are ***not*** desired.

Comment: Posted an answer but just a workaround for this specific dataset, `HairEyeColor[,,1]+HairEyeColor[,,2]`

Answer (score 5):

We do a group by summarise and then `spread`

```
library(tidyerse)
HEC %>% 
    group_by(Hair, Eye) %>% 
    summarise(Freq = sum(Freq)) %>%
    spread(Eye, Freq)
```

---

It can be also done in a one-liner

```
xtabs(Freq ~ Eye + Hair, HEC)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do it with `tapply()`:

```
tapply(HEC$Freq, list(ColHair=HEC$Hair,ColEye=HEC$Eye), sum)


  #         ColEye
  # ColHair Brown Blue Hazel Green
  # Black    68   20    15     5
  # Brown   119   84    54    29
  # Red      26   17    14    14
  # Blond     7   94    10    16
```

---

---

Or using `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(HEC)[,list(Freq=sum(Freq)),by=list(Hair, Eye)]

  #     Hair    Eye    Freq
  # 1:  Black   Brown   68
  # 2:  Brown   Brown  119
  # 3:    Red   Brown   26
  # 4:  Blond   Brown    7
  # 5:  Black   Blue    20
  # 6:  Brown   Blue    84
  # 7:    Red   Blue    17
  # 8:  Blond   Blue    94
  # 9:  Black   Hazel   15
  # 10: Brown   Hazel   54
  # 11:   Red   Hazel   14
  # 12: Blond   Hazel   10
  # 13: Black   Green    5
  # 14: Brown   Green   29
  # 15:   Red   Green   14
  # 16: Blond   Green   16
```

To get it in cross-tab format:

```
HEC_tab <- dcast(setDT(HEC)[,list(Freq=sum(Freq)),by=list(Hair, Eye)], 
                                         Hair~Eye, value.var = "Freq")

setnames(HEC_tab , c("HairCol/EyeCol", names(HEC_tab)[-1]))

HEC_tab

  #   HairCol/EyeCol Brown Blue Hazel Green
  # 1:         Black    68   20    15     5
  # 2:         Brown   119   84    54    29
  # 3:           Red    26   17    14    14
  # 4:         Blond     7   94    10    16
```